# *minimum cut is always the same in flow networks?

Tags: graph-algorithm

I've seen a way of finding a minimum cut in a flow network N=(V,E,c,s,t) by:

1. find a maximum flow f in the network N (using a Ford-Fulkerson based algo. for example).
2. set S to contain all vertices v with paths from s to v in the residual network of f.
3. set T=V\S
4. return (S,T)

For any maximal flow f, will this cut (S,T) always be the same?
It seems true, but I'm having trouble explaining this.

(namely, if f,f' are max flows, and (S,T), (S',T') are the cuts the algorithm above outputed, then S=S',T=T')

*There might be other minimum cuts, but I'm reffering to minimum cuts obtained this way.

Answer (score 0):

its not exactly the same because:

[image]

in this example you can have 2 different cuts in that way,some time the upper node will be in S,some time in T,depends where the algo run the flow(the upper edge from s,you the lower one).